# Dates being treated as text even when TO_DATE() is used

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently pulling out my hair because I cannot seem to understand why these date cells aren't being converted to the date format when the TO_DATE() formula is used. Here is my [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WD31DXY4Xi1cY8Zu0cQ4LyV7xXOwudN3fDlpj1k0Cm8/edit?usp=sharing) (IDs are randomly generated in this case).

The Data sheet is just that, it is static data that is manually updated. Please note the dates in the Data sheet have a ' prefix. The B3 cell in the VLOOKUP sheet is the formula I am struggling with. I have written the formula to remove the ' prefix and convert the text to date formatting, unfortunately either I have done something wrong (quite likely) or Google is toying with me.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(IF(LEN(A3:A),VLOOKUP(A3:A,Data!A3:B,2,0)*1,"")))
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work perfectly. It seems I may have been using the TO_DATE() formula in the wrong location. I have noticed the multiplication action forced the text to a number, I will have to remember this trick.